# Use radioButtons to select alphabetic characters in silverlight (xaml)

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, radio-button, converters

I am making a silverlight widget, where I will need the users to be able to select alphabetic characters in a grid like this:

[image]

And if I click on the a in the top row, it shall look like this:

[image]

In the viewmodel it will be represented like a string like a chararray, so that 1 contains an array with a, i and 2 contains an array with d, h and so on.

Now, my question is, what is the best way to represent this?

My initial idea was to have radioButtons, grouped by letter.

```
<RadioButton GroupName="a" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" IsChecked="{Binding 1, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BSMClassConverter}, ConverterParameter='a'}" ></RadioButton>
<RadioButton GroupName="a" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" IsChecked="{Binding 2, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BSMClassConverter}, ConverterParameter='a'}" ></RadioButton>
<RadioButton GroupName="a" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" IsChecked="{Binding 3, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BSMClassConverter}, ConverterParameter='a'}" ></RadioButton>
```

And then have a converter to convert the info to a string. But I cannot wrap my head around how this is going to work. I hope there is someone out there with a good idea :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but this works, using commands rather than converters:

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <RadioButton Content="a" GroupName="a" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding UpdateSelection}" CommandParameter="1;a" />
    <RadioButton Content="a" GroupName="a" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding UpdateSelection}" CommandParameter="2;a" />
    <RadioButton Content="a" GroupName="a" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding UpdateSelection}" CommandParameter="3;a" />

    <RadioButton Content="b" GroupName="B" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding UpdateSelection}" CommandParameter="1;b" />
    <RadioButton Content="b" GroupName="B" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding UpdateSelection}" CommandParameter="2;b" />
    <RadioButton Content="b" GroupName="B" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding UpdateSelection}" CommandParameter="3;b" />

    <RadioButton Content="c" GroupName="C" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding UpdateSelection}" CommandParameter="1;c" />
    <RadioButton Content="c" GroupName="C" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding UpdateSelection}" CommandParameter="3;c" />
    <RadioButton Content="c" GroupName="C" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding UpdateSelection}" CommandParameter="3;c" />

</Grid>
```

And in your ViewModel:

```
List<string> row1List = new List<string>();
    List<string> row2List = new List<string>();
    List<string> row3List = new List<string>();

    public RelayCommand<string> UpdateSelection { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        UpdateSelection = new RelayCommand<string>((str) => UpdateSelectionExecute(str));
    }

    private void UpdateSelectionExecute(string str)
    {
        string[] split = str.Split(';');

        switch (split[0])
        {
            case "1":
                Remove(split[1]);
                row1List.Add(split[1]);
                break;
            case "2":
                Remove(split[1]);
                row2List.Add(split[1]);
                break;
            case "3":
                Remove(split[1]);
                row3List.Add(split[1]);
                break;
        }

        OutputToConsole();

    }

    private void Remove(string character)
    {
        if (row1List.Contains(character))
        {
            row1List.Remove(character);
        }

        if (row2List.Contains(character))
        {
            row2List.Remove(character);
        }

        if (row3List.Contains(character))
        {
            row3List.Remove(character);
        }
    }  

    private void OutputToConsole()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("List 1: ");
        row1List.OrderBy(o => o).ToList().ForEach((c) => Console.Write(c));
        Console.WriteLine("");


        Console.WriteLine("List 2: ");
        row2List.OrderBy(o => o).ToList().ForEach((c) => Console.Write(c));
        Console.WriteLine("");


        Console.WriteLine("List 3: ");
        row3List.OrderBy(o => o).ToList().ForEach((c) => Console.Write(c));
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
```